# Extract SQL from Subsonic 3

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Is there a way to extract the SQL which is run against the database from a bit of subsonic?  For instance I have

```
foreach (var item in EVT.All().Where(e => e.EVT_USRNAME == "stimms"))
        {
         ...
        }
```

Can I get at what is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Subsonic, you can get the command which will be executing against a query in this way:

```
IQueryable query = EVT.All().Where(e => e.EVT_USRNAME == "stimms");
SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider provider = (SubSonic.Linq.Structure.DbQueryProvider)query.Provider;
string command = provider.GetCommand(query.Expression).CommandSql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simon,
Another method that requires more under-hood revelation is to debug the Subsonic source-code.  Set a breakpoint at your query, watch the evaluated statement, and look for the QueryText property.

MAbraham1